# How do I get user input to use my validate method for a login console application?

Tags: c#, authentication, methods, console-application, user-input

Basically I want to be able to ask the user the enter their details and from the user input I want to be able to cross check the credentials with data in a text file which I have already setup I am simply just having trouble figuring out a way to use the method and take in the users input.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("PLEASE ENTER CORRECT DETAILS TO LOGIN");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Username: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
     
    }
```

Is it possible to get users input to cross check using this method:

```
    public bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\K\Desktop\Accounts\login.txt";
        string[] logininfo = File.ReadAllLines(filePath + @"C:\Users\K\Desktop\Accounts\login.txt");

        foreach (string detail in logininfo)
        {
            users user = new users(detail);
            if (user.username == username && user.password == password)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: you want to get keyboard inputs from user?

Comment: There is no need to load the file each time we check credentials (unless you expect them to change while the app is running). Load it once on start and then use the credentials from file to compare them to what user has entered. For that you'd also need to save his input that you get from `Console.ReadLine` to a variable

Comment: @hackerbuddy thanks for the reply and yes keyboard input.

Comment: @Fabjan thank you for the reply and I will definitely need to look at it again and clean it up, i will take into account the points you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just store the value you read from the console and pass it to the `validate` function. Since you are reading a string you don't need any casting. If you are reading a value which is not a string such as Integer, you have to consider type casting.

`int value = Int32.Prase(Console.ReadLine());`

Since you have not do so, this code will solve your problem.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("PLEASE ENTER CORRECT DETAILS TO LOGIN");
    
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Username: ");
    var username = Console.ReadLine();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Password: ");
    var password = Console.ReadLine();
    
    var isValid = validate(username, password); 
}
```